# Hibernate + Spring boot 2: Not checking the default schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am running a Spring Boot app with Hibernate. I have the following properties in my "application.properties" to load a Mysql Datasource and set Hibernate properties. But When I run Integration tests with the following properties, Hibernate tends to check "information_schema" as default schema and not "knowledgedb" schema and it fails with the below exception.

Mysql connector version: 8.0.12

Spring Boot version: 2.1.3.RELEASE

Exception:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'book_version' in information_schema
```

properties:

```
# Spring Datasource properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/knowledgedb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&characterEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=utf8&useTimezone=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=XX
spring.datasource.password=XX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

# Hibernate specific properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=knowledgedb
```

Comment: try using databaseName=knowledgedb instead of only name

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan: SQL doesnt like the URL syntax

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan: databaseName=knowledgedb  in the URL is not the right syntax

Comment: i hav not used SQL but read in more than one doc https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: In configuration file, mark requried datasource as primary bean

Answer (score 0):

@Abhi.G have you already created schema/database into db ?? If no then create it manually and then check whether it works or not ! Normally,if you have written correct property file then it creates database itself.
Please do this change in your file and try again :
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update